# Python C API: Import module with absolute file path

Tags: python-c-api

I'm prototyping a Python C extension which should be able to import a large number of python modules very quickly with minimum overhead. 
My extension will know the module names and their absolute paths based on it's own logic. I'd like to avoid using the built-in import mechanism (i.e. I don't need to look up the sys.path to find the module) and avoid using **importlib** whatsoever because it's a huge overhead with a hundred modules.

I'm trying to find a clean C-API alternative of this:

```py
from importlib import util
spec = util.spec_from_file_location("stub", "/ars/python/stub.py")
stub = util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(stub)
```

I've seen recommendations like this

```cc
PySys_SetPath("path/with/python/files");
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("filename_without_extension");
```

This is still searches the **sys.path** and I need to avoid it.

```cc
PyObject *imp = PyImport_ImportModule("imp");
PyObject_CallMethod(imp , "load_source", args, "<my_mod>", "<mod_path>");
```

This one uses an old **imp** module and prints deprecation warnings. It's not clear how to replace it with the new **importlib** since there is no such a high-level **load_source** method as in the old **imp**.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks.